# how to localize and fix this error :Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module?

Tags: deployment, cpanel, nuxtjs3

I am very new to node devel and trying to deploy a NUXT3 app embryo on my shared hosting that uses CPanel and a tool named Setup Node.js App to create node applications.
The aim is to ensure that I will be able to install my app on this hosting before going further in its development.
At the moment the app runs locally, shows only some empty pages and provides a register/login functionality.
On my hosting I am limited to node version 20.9.0 (npm 10.1.0), therefore I developed my app with this node version.
I build my app localy and installed the content of .output to a compta-node folder at the root of my hosting.

I then created a sub-domain compta-mydomain.fr

I used the Setup Node.js App tool to create a node application  with these settings:

node version: 20.9.0

App Root: compta-node

Application URL: compta.mydomain.fr

Application startup file : server/index.jms

Then I add an env varialble DATABASE_URL with the url that I used before to initialize the database successfully.

After launching the node app from CPanel, and pointing to https://compta.mydomain.fr
I got the following error

> The Phusion Passenger(R) application server tried to start the web
> application through a Passenger-internal helper tool called the
> "wrapper". But Passenger was unable to execute that helper tool
> because it encountered an internal error.
>
> The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:
>
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089
> throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, true);
> ^
>
> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
> /home4/denentza/compta-node/server/index.mjs not supported. Instead
> change the require of /home4/denentza/compta-node/server/index.mjs to
> a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
> at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
> at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
> at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
> at Object. (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1)
> {   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' }
>
> Node.js v20.9.0

Here are some snapshots of what I get. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]
[image]